# Java: Create multiple content panes and switch between them

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, awt

I am creating my first Java GUI application and I want to have multiple screen/panes. So far I have created two Java froms. One is called HomeInterface.form and the other is called RestockInterface.form.

However, I want to switch between both JPanels by clicking the buttons. The problem here is, I don't know how to implement this probably. At the moment everytime I click the Button `backToHomeInterfaceButton` a new JFrame get created. Also, I have to create a new HomeInterface object in order to get the rootPanel. This is ridiculous.

Do you guys know how I can implement this probably without creating a new object and frame each time? I want to keep the same frame and just switch between the different rootPanels without creating a new one each time.

Please keep in mind, I don't want to use CardLayout or TabbedLayout, I am using the IntelliJ GridLayout and want to keep this!

HomeInterface.form code:

```
public class HomeInferface{
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JButton thisIsMyButtonButton;
    private JPanel test;

    public HomeInferface(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Beispiel Frame");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(rootPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        thisIsMyButtonButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SellInterface sellInterface = new SellInterface();
                frame.setContentPane(sellInterface.getRootPanel());
                frame.revalidate();
            }
        });

        public JPanel getRootPanel() {
            return rootPanel;
        }
    }
}
```

RestockForm.form:

```
public class RestockInterface {
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JButton backToHomeInterfaceButton;

    public RestockInterface(JFrame frame) {
        backToHomeInterfaceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                HomeInferface homeInterface = new HomeInferface();                    
                frame.setContentPane(homeInterface.getRootPanel());
                frame.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getRootPanel() {
        return rootPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This, `"Please keep in mind, I don't want to use CardLayout ....., I am using the IntelliJ GridLayout and want to keep this!"` really doesn't make sense as you know that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout, and so using one layout does not preclude using another. The canonical solution is and remains: use a CardLayout. Period.

Comment: Agree -- the above is your solution

Comment: `I don't want to use CardLayout` - the parent panel uses the CardLayout. The individuals panels you add to the panel using CardLayout can use whatever layout you want.

Comment: Alright, thank you guys. However, I still don’t know how to implement tho probably... could you give me some tips?

Comment: You've gotten all the tips you need -- remember to **nest** JPanels, add one (or more) inside of another, each using its own layout

Comment: @Jan check out this [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/719it8encpj8leh/CardDemo.zip?dl=0) for IntelliJ IDEA. Does it help?